# How to write IF and ELSE in batch file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion


SET /P tool=Please enter the tool name: 

If %tool%=="fw-test.exe" (echo "The tool name is fw-test.exe") else (echo "Unknown tool name") 

If %tool%=="ick-test.exe" (echo "The tool name is ick-test.exe") else (echo "Unknown tool name")
```

I get a syntax error. How I should write for working properly?

Comment: Remove `@echo off` and check the command echoes. What do you enter in the `set /P` prompt causing the syntax error?

Comment: I enter **fw-test.exe**

Comment: Well, this should not cause a syntax error; I'd expect such when you don't enter anything and just press _enter_...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do 2 separate if statements, the one should include the other in the `else` statement, else you will get both results `tool name.exe` and `unknown tool name` simply because if matches the first, but not the second:

```
@echo off
:select
set /p tool=Please enter the tool name: 

If /i "%tool%"=="fw-test.exe" (
    echo "The tool name is fw-test.exe"
) else (
    If /i "%tool%"=="ick-test.exe" (
        echo "The tool name is ick-test.exe"
    ) else (
        echo Unknown Tool please retry
        goto select
    )
)
```

**Note** that I am evaluating both sides of `==` with double quotes. Else you will never get a match. This is wrong: `if var=="var"` as the one is not quoted where this: `if "var"=="var"` will match exactly. I Included the `/I` option as well as it will allow for the name to be typed as `FW-TEST.exe` as well as mixed case.

if you were planning on only using selected pre-defined tools, simply use choice instead. It will allow the user to only choose one of the 2 tools:

```
@echo off

echo 1. fw-test.exe
echo 2. ick-test.exe
choice /c 12 /m "Select a tool"
goto tool%errorlevel%
:tool1
Set "tool=fw-test.exe"
goto show
:tool2
Set "tool=ick-test.exe"
goto show
:show
echo you have selected %tool%
pause
```

Comment: How I can write a function that when I will write in the answer of this "Please enter the tool name:" the unknown tool it will ask me to enter the valid tool name.

Comment: Rather then use the choice option as I have shown. There you can specify what you want the user to select and only use valid tool options.

Comment: In that option you write tool1 and tool2 but in my code I write if %tool% with if statement, it means that I have only the name tool.   ECHO The tool name is: %tool%

if "%tool%"=="fw-test.exe" (
    set toolpath1=%exbuild1%\SW\test_w32\fw-test.exe
    set toolpath2=%exbuild2%\SW\test_w32\fw-test.exe

Comment: In that example `tool1` and `tool2` are labels and not the variable. It does not seem as if you need a variable here as you are enforcing specific tools. Do you have a specific list of valid tools you want to present to a user?

Comment: Have a look at how I changed the last example to still set a variable and use that variable in the `:show` label. But I also updated the original code to do what you wanted in the comment.